# what happens if LIMIT or OFFSET is set to 0?

Tags: mysql

is 0 the default for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If LIMIT is 0 you will get an empty result set
- adding OFFSET 0 is a [NOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) - it won't have any effect

Comment: thank you. but don't you know what value(/s) would be for LIMIT so that there's no effect either?

Comment: I am not aware of any such thing and I doubt that it exists. You might want to check the mysql docs, though: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: yeah, have found nothing so far.